# Glob expression as an argument can not be printed

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, globbing

I am trying to write a simple bash script which would print the argument provided as an input to the terminal.

```
echo "${1-nothing}"
```

I have tried using $@ or without quotes. If I enter `*` as an argument the * will not be printed out but instead the name of the bash file would be. How can I simply print the * as an Argument ?

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: If you run the script with something like `./script.sh *`, the shell expands `*` to a list of files, and passes those as arguments to the script. The script never sees the "*", and has no way to tell that's what was typed on the command like. You **must** quote or escape wildcards in order to pass them as part of an actual argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${1-nothing}"
```

and that you did `chmod a+x` for this script.

When you type `./script.sh *`, the shell that you type in will interpret this command. `./script.sh` means start the script. `*` here means all the names of the files and directories in the current directory. So, `script.sh`, `possibly_another_file` et cetera. So, what gets executed is:

```
./script.sh script.sh possibly_another_file
```

You can try `echo *` to see the actual list in your directory.

But now, you do not want the `*` to be expanded by the shell that you type in. The simplest solution is to quote the `*`, as in

```
./script.sh '*'
```

The shell will not expand the quoted string.

You can also say to the shell, that the `*` must be interpreted as the character `*` and not as the Glob. You would use a `\` for that, as in

```
./script.sh \*
```